# Make checkbox bound to nullable bool transition from null to true

Tags: wpf, binding, checkbox

I have a checkbox with its `IsChecked` property bound to a nullable bool.  When my control first loads the value is null and the checkbox appears greyed out.  This is what I want.

When the user clicks the checkbox, it moves to the false/Unchecked state.

However, 99% of the time the user is going to want to tick the checkbox - which currently means double clicking the checkbox.

How can I make the value move from null to true when the user first clicks the checkbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just modify the setter of the bound property to check whether the previous value is null and if it is, set the value to `true`. Something like this:

```
public bool? MyBoolProperty 
{
   get { return _myBoolProperty; }
   set 
   {
       _myBoolProperty = (_myBoolProperty != null || value == null) ? value : true;
       RaisePropertyChanged("MyBoolProperty");       
   }
}
```

The binding system will re-read the property after it sets it, so the new value will be reflected by the `CheckBox`.

Comment: This will affect code trying to set the property as well, which is fairly dodgy.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and ran into this question. This is a late response but I think this is the best solution :)

With the help of `IsThreeState` and `TargetNullValue` you can accomplish this

```
 <CheckBox  IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding YOUR_NULLABLE_PROPERTY, TargetNullValue=false}" />
```

The only caveat is that it will toggle between null and true. There will never be a false value.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the Click event and implement a logic like this:

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

  switch (cb.IsChecked) 
  {
    case null:
      cb.IsChecked = false;
      break;

    case true:
      cb.IsChecked = true;
      break;

    case false:
      if (cb.IsThreeState) {
        cb.IsChecked = null;
      } else {
        cb.IsChecked = true;
      }
      break;
  }

  e.Handled = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have met this problem recently. I look all answers of this question, but none seem fit me. The accepted answer is fail when I set `IsChecked` equals false in ViewModel. I decompile the checkbox in wpf. 
As you can see, when you click a null `IsChecked` checkbox, `IsChecked` property will switch to false.

```
protected internal virtual void OnToggle()
{
    bool? flag;
    if (this.IsChecked == true)
    {
        flag = (this.IsThreeState ? null : new bool?(false));
    }
    else
    {
        flag = new bool?(this.IsChecked.HasValue);
    }
    base.SetCurrentValueInternal(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, flag);
}
```

So you can Create a new class inherit `CheckBox` and override `OnToggle` method like this:

```
protected override void OnToggle()
{
   bool? flag;
   if (this.IsChecked == true)
   {
       flag = this.IsThreeState ? null : new bool?(false);
   }
   else 
       flag = true;
   // what a pity this method is internal
   // actually you can call this method by reflection
   base.SetCurrentValueInternal(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, flag);
}
```

The other way is:

```
protected override void OnToggle()
{
    if (this.IsChecked == null)
        this.IsChecked = false;
    base.OnToggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to simply handle the `click` event and set the control to `true` if its current state is `null`, optionally setting a `flag` for your internal code tracking after first click.