# WPF: set false as default for all checkbox controll

Tags: wpf, checkbox, targetnullvalue

I have many checkbox binding nullable bool values and when I press on the control, if it's set to null, I have to press twice to get true.
Is it possible to have true as the first value or false as default when I have null for all the checkbox, for example with a style?

I've tried with this before, and it works:

```
<CheckBox  IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding MY_NULLABLE_PROPERTY, TargetNullValue=false}"/>
```

but I would like a generic solution for each control

**EDITED:**

I need to handle the problem for checkbox inside datagrid as well

Comment: You can add one or more ResourceDictionaries containing global `Styles` to your `App.xaml` as described for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569974/wpf-global-style

Comment: Yes, my idea was to use a global style, but I need to set the false value only when IsCheched is null

Comment: Yes, my bad not to have seen you mentioning Styles already. This following SO thread seems to cover your first option: _" Is it possible to have true as the first value"_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313998/make-checkbox-bound-to-nullable-bool-transition-from-null-to-true

Comment: It only partially solves the problem. However, it is necessary to modify all the checkboxes of the project or create a custom checkbox to replace all the controls already in use. But there is a further problem: it does not work with checkboxes inside the datagrid